# Mostrar dos columnas de un una misma tabla con datos diferentes. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Primero que todo, muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Tengo un problema que no logro solucionar, tengo:

Una tabla llamada dbo.Comidas que necesito obtener 2 resultados diferentes con la función `COUNT()`. Una columna mostrará las `Comidas totales` y la otra `Comidas servidas`.

Pero el problema es que no logro que me muestra ese resultado correctamente, me sale un error de desbordamiento o cuando hago una subconsulta en el SELECT

> Solo se puede especificar una expresión en la lista de selección
>   cuando la subconsulta no se especifica con EXISTS.

Os adjunto la consulta:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CO.ComidaId) AS [Total Comidas],

(SELECT
    COUNT(C.ComidaId) AS [ComidasServidas],
    CENT.CentroNombre
FROM 
    dbo.Comidas C
    INNER JOIN dbo.Centros CENT ON C.CentroId  = CENT.CentroId
    WHERE 
    C.TarjetaEmplatadoActualId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    CENT.CentroNombre
            ) AS COTE,
CNTR.CentroNombre
FROM dbo.Comidas CO
    INNER JOIN dbo.Centros CNTR ON CO.CentroId = CNTR.CentroId
WHERE CO.Servir = 1
GROUP BY CNTR.CentroNombre
```

Como podéis ver, una condición es que tenga la columna `Servir = 1`
y la otra es que la columna `TarjetaEmplatadoActualId` no sea nulo.

Necesito mostrarlo en 3 columnas, no puedo hacer `UNION ALL` ya que eso me muestra los datos en 2 columnas y hacia abajo. Pensé en FULL JOIN, pero no se como ejecutarlo correctamente.

Muchas gracias por su atención.
Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes hacerlo asi, ya que la subconsulta aplicada en un campo **SOLO** debe devolver un unico valor.

Yo haría así.

```
    SELECT

        CENT.CentroNombre,
COUNT(C.ComidaId) AS [ComidasServidas]
    FROM 
        dbo.Comidas C
        INNER JOIN dbo.Centros CENT ON C.CentroId  = CENT.CentroId
        WHERE 
        C.TarjetaEmplatadoActualId IS NOT NULL AND C.Servir=1
    GROUP BY 
        CENT.CentroNombre  
        UNION
        SELECT 'TOTAL',
        COUNT(CO.ComidaId) AS [Total Comidas]
        FROM dbo.Comidas CO
             INNER JOIN dbo.Centros CNTR ON CO.CentroId = CNTR.CentroId
        WHERE CO.Servir = 1
```

El resultado que se consigue es que desde la primera fila hasta la N-1 sean la cantidad de comidas agrupadas por centros y la ultima fila sea el TOTAL.

```
Centro          Comidas Servidas
   x              x
   x              x
....

TOTAL             X
```

No se si te puede valer esto.

Comment: Te agradezco el comentario ¡, pero realmente tengo que mostrar una columna mas con los datos de 'comidas servidas'. Estuve investigando el FULL JOIN pero estoy bastante perdido de como emplearlo correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Como el error te indica no es posible tener en una consulta datos con diferentes criterios (WHERE). Debes hacer dos consultas distintas, aunque las puedes juntar para obtener los dos resultados conjuntamente.

En el siguiente código se realiza un select que apunta al resultado de dos sub consultas, la primera devuelve las comidas servidas y la segunda el total. Revisa los `WHERE` puede que no sean correctos, pero te puede dar una idea clara de como proceder. Las dos consultas se unen con un `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT CENT.CentroNombre, COUNT(C.ComidaId) AS [ComidasServidas]
FROM dbo.Comidas C
INNER JOIN dbo.Centros CENT ON C.CentroId  = CENT.CentroId
WHERE C.TarjetaEmplatadoActualId IS NOT NULL AND CO.Servir = 1
GROUP BY CENT.CentroNombre
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL' as CentroNombre, COUNT(C.ComidaId) AS [ComidasServidas],     
FROM dbo.Comidas C
INNER JOIN dbo.Centros CENT ON C.CentroId  = CENT.CentroId
WHERE C.TarjetaEmplatadoActualId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CENT.CentroNombre
```

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS ¡ Realmente me has ayudado mucho. He entendido el funcionamiento que planteas y es algo lógico. No había llegado a esta conclusión. Te lo agradezco mucho @RogerTomé

Comment: Acabo de ver lo último de la pregunta y creo que la respuesta no se adapta exactamente a lo que querías, lo reviso

Comment: Ya la he editado, ahora aparece el total en la última línea